# 2.92 Fire & Smoke Definition

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, smoke-simulation, fire, blur

Using 2.92, trying to work on outdated tutorials and struggling. I have my subdivisions set at 1052 so there’s no reason for the fire and smoke to be blurry, but it still is. There’s no colour mapping tool as used in some tutorials and I just can’t figure out how to give my fire and smoke more definition and detail.
Please, please help. I’m going crazy.

Comment: Sometimes having a high emissive value for volumetrics causes my volume to look lower quality. Maybe try lowering the emissive value if present?

Comment: Are you using cycles?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, whether this helps others or not, I don't know.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOYUw.jpg

[image: New smoke]

[image: Node settings]